# Unable to access CouchDB from remotely in AWS Ubuntu EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, couchdb

I have tried of available answer but still not able to find out the solution

Here I have steps which I have followed

`sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:couchdb/stable -y`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get remove couchdb couchdb-bin couchdb-common -yf`

`sudo apt-get install couchdb -y`

after when I run

`curl localhost:5984`

I get the desired output

`Output {"couchdb":"Welcome","uuid":"b9f278c743b5fc0b971c4e587d77582e","version":"1.6.1","vendor":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"14.04"}}`

But when I run

`sudo stop couchdb`

I get output as `sudo: stop: command not found`

and when I run

`sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /usr/lib/couchdb /usr/share/couchdb /etc/couchdb /usr/bin/couchdb`

output is

`chown: cannot access '/usr/lib/couchdb': No such file or directory`

and when I run

`ssh -L5984:127.0.0.1:5984 ubuntu@server_ip`

I get

`Warning: Identity file -L5984:127.0.0.1:5984 not accessible: No such file or directory. Permission denied (publickey).`

Can anybody help me out in this?

Comment: While trying to create tunnel specify the key name as well. So the command should be : ssh -i key_name.pem -L 5984:127.0.0.1:5984 ubuntu@server_ip

Comment: I haven't used couchdb but for "sudo stop couchdb" you seem to be missing service in the middle. I think it should "sudo service couchdb stop".